# recursion binary search in a list of names

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search-tree

I am trying to build a function that gets the index of an item form a list

```
names = [('Daisy','Fox'),('Josh','Belluga'),('Elin','Grosefield'),('Mike','Levinsan')]
```

this is the code

```
def find_name(lst,name,low,high):
if low >= high:
    return None
middle = (low + high) / 2
if lst[middle] == name:
    return middle
elif name < lst[middle]:
    return find_name(lst, name, low, middle)
else:
    return find_name(lst, name, middle + 1, high)
```

it works fine and all but the only problem that im having is when I define the low and high values to be equals for the index I want to get
for example

```
print find_name(names,('Josh','Belluga'),0,1)
```

returns none when it should return 1 for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def find_name(lst,name,low,high):
    if high is None:
         high = len(lst) - 1 


    if low > high:

         return False 

    middle = (low + high) / 2
    if lst[middle] == name:
         return middle
    elif name < lst[middle]:
        return find_name(lst, name, low, middle-1)
    else:
         return find_name(lst, name, middle + 1, high)




names = [('Daisy','Fox'),('Josh','Belluga'),('Elin','Grosefield'),('Mike','Levinsan')]


print find_name(names, ('Josh','Belluga'), 0, 1)
```

Here is what you are looking for. Just compare your original code with this and you will see what you did wrong.